# error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular

Есть структура проекта, где в папке src есть папки app и spa на
одном уровне. В app - app.module.ts, в spa - spa.module.ts.
Возникает ошибка при запуске проекта - error NG6002: Appears in
the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to
an NgModule class.

```
**app.module.ts**

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SpaModule } from 'src/spa/spa.module';

  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, SpaModule
    ],  
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

**spa.module.ts**

import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { SpaBodyComponent } from './spa-body/spa- 
body.component';
import { SpaHeaderComponent } from './spa-header/spa- 
header.component';
import { SpaContentComponent } from './spa-content/spa- 
content.component';
import { SpaFooterComponent } from './spa-footer/spa- 
footer.component';

NgModule ({
imports: [CommonModule],
declarations: [SpaBodyComponent, SpaHeaderComponent, 
SpaContentComponent, SpaFooterComponent],
exports: [SpaBodyComponent]
})
export class SpaModule {}

**app.component.ts**

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'car-fest';
}

**app.component.html**

<spa-header></spa-header>
<spa-content></spa-content>
<spa-footer></spa-footer>

Spa-компоненты ещё пустые, то есть только созданы стандартным 
методом и всё. Буду благодарен за помощь!
```

Comment: Зачем и почему оны на одном уровне? киньте модуль spa внуть app

Comment: Переместил - ошибка не исчезла! Путь к SpaModule у меня - 'src/app/spa/spa.module' - ошибки не чертит. Error: src/app/spa/spa.module.ts:13:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?

export class SpaModule {}

Comment: Опечатка? У spa модуле не находит `@NgModule` - и в коде вашем его тоже есть, есть непонятно что -> `NgModule`

Comment: Не понял ваш ответ. Что у меня не так и что сделать для исправления ошибки?

Comment: `NgModule` замените на `@NgModule` в spa.module

Comment: Заменил - ошибка пропала, но появились другие: 
Error: src/app/app.component.html:8:1 - error NG8001: 'spa-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'spa-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'spa-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

8 <spa-header></spa-header> И так со всеми тремя компонентами, что есть у меня. И ещё, в конце указание что ошибка происходит в app.component -  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Comment: Добавьте компоненты в  exports spa.module

Comment: Спасибо, работает!